# How PDOConnection from Doctrine works?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

It's not a question about a Doctrine feature but how Doctrine achieve a feature.

In Doctrine2, there is a mechanism I don't understand.

Using [PDOConnection](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php), *prepare* method return a [PDOStatement](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php) but PDOConnection extends \PDO.

Since *prepare* return *parent::prepare*, how does it return PDOStatement instead of \PDOStatement ?

Thanks

Comment: "_...how does it return PDOStatement instead of \PDOStatement..._" - I dont know exactly what you're asking, but those appears to be the same class

Comment: \PDOStatement is the class returned by \PDO. For PDOStatement, I was talking about Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found it.

It's done in the Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection constructor :

```
$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement', array()));
```

Actually, it's not a php mechanism, it's a \PDO feature.

I was searching since yesterday and it's after my question on stackoverflow i've found it ...

Comment: Didn't knew PDO had this feature as well. Thanks for sharing